# How to determine what kind of curve in 3d geometry

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am having difficulty in determining type of given curve in 3d geometry.Is there any test in which I can differentiate between

1) Circle

2) Cone

3) Cylinder

4) Circle

When equation of 3d curve is given as $ax^2 +by^2 + cz^2 + dx + ey + fz + g=0 $

Comment: By chance, did you write the formula down wrong? Should the sixth term be $fz$ instead of $fc$?

Comment: yes , sorry for typo.

Comment: The equation will give you a "surface", not a "curve". (So, your two "Circle" options, (1) and (4), are irrelevant.) Anyway ... To distinguish among the many types of surfaces that the equation can describe, see [MathWorld's "Quadratic Surface" entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html).